# Laptop won't turn on, but still feels warm?

Tags: laptop, cpu, bios, power-supply, battery

I have an HP Elitebook 840 G4 that won't turn on but still feels warm. I tried holding the power button for 15 seconds. The power light and caps lock both illuminate for 3 seconds then turn off and nothing else happens.

It has a non-removable battery but I managed to open it up and remove the battery. I determined the CPU is where the heat is coming from, not the battery. With the battery removed, the CPU cools down, but as soon as I plug the battery back in the CPU begins to heat up as if the laptop is on. With the battery removed, I tried holding the power button for 15 seconds to remove any static. I also tried unplugging the CMOS battery for 15 minutes in case of BIOS issues.

None of those methods worked and the symptom has remained the same. If battery is plugged in the CPU will warm up as though it is on.

Any solutions to this issue? What could have caused this?

Comment: I don't think it is in sleep mode since the battery was out for like 20 minutes, there's no way it was getting power. It cooled off while the battery was out but soon as I put it back in it starts warming up again.

Comment: That’s a dead motherboard. Time to get a new computer or have it fixed under warranty. You could purchase a different motherboard, but I’m not sure if it would be worth the cost or hassle. That’s an eBay thing and you never know what your getting. Often some goofball put the motherboard in an oven and called it “refurbished” then sold it for $300 to some sucker.

Comment: Appleoddity's right.

Comment: @Appleoddity You were correct sir. Confirmed dead motherboard by IT department today and got a replacement laptop.